# Sophisticated positive or negative

Tags: meaning

When I searched for the meaning of the word sophisticated ,it does mean well advanced ,highly complicated etc. When I say my project is sophisticated what impression it can possibly make.
The project is good that it is advanced or the project is really complicated to understand . Can I use that word in such situations

Comment: What idea about your project do you want to convey?

Comment: that my project is well advanced

Comment: What do you mean by "well advanced"? Do you mean that its development is nearly finished? What have you found when you looked for *sophisticated* in a couple of dictionaries (more than one is always a good idea).

Comment: I think 'sophisticated' has  a positive bias unless you say 'too sophisticated' or 'unnecessarily sophisticated'.

Comment: Yes 'sophisticated' carries very positive messages as @Josh61 points out.

Answer (score 1):

Sophisticated has a positive bias, so you can use that word to imply good things about your project. However, it has always struck me as a contrast to simple-minded or uncultured (see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophisticated)). I think you may be looking for something more along the lines of **complex**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that will depend on the overall context of your description of your project.

If your project is well conceived  and successfully implemented, then to describe it additionally as 'sophisticated' will imply that it has been cleverly designed.

If, on the other hand, it is plagued with technical problems and has fallen considerably behind schedule, then to describe it additionally as 'sophisticated' will imply that its design is over-complicated and has made the project too difficult for you to handle.